# JFrog Artifactory stopped working in Android Studio. apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'

Tags: android, artifactory

From yesterday August 31, 2023 i am facing issue with gradle sync in Android Studio. i am using

```
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

```
repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/artifactory/libs-release-local"
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_username}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

Suddenly the gradle sync stopped working. And the same issue happening on different laptops. Is google restricted artifactory libraries? can anyone suggest on this.

Issue:

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':camera_library2'.
> Failed to apply plugin class 'org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPlugin'.
> Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Action) when the project is already evaluated.

I tried with upgrading and downgrading gradle versions and kotlin versions. still didnt find any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with jfrog artifactory latest versions.
5.1.4, 5.1.5 which released on August 30 & 31 having issues.
Till 5.1.2 its working fine.

Working:

> classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:5.1.2"